# This isn`t working on firefox? How can i fix it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I tried many versions with window, body and html but nothing working. Where is my mistake?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('#link').click(function () {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: 0
            }, 2000);
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: What happens if you open the Firefox JavaScript console and reload the page?  What error message, if any, do you get?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should pass `event` in the event handler function like

```
 $('#link').click(function (event) {
```